# Unable to access samba server

Tags: linux, centos, samba

I can't connect to my samba server running CentOS 6.4 (minimal installation) that is **not** located within my network.

When I try to connect with my Windows 7 client, the connection fails and I get the default "unable to access " dialog displayed.

What I've tried so far:

- Opened ports 137, 138, 139, 445 on my samba server
- Verified that the ports are open by using nmap (on the samba server)
- Tried to telnet on the mentioned ports above from my client but the connection also failed
- Reinstalled samba and reconfigured the service
- turned off SELinux temporary

**iptables**

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:netbios-ns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

**nmap**

```
#nmap -sTU -O localhost

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-05-16 17:29 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000042s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 1994 closed ports
PORT    STATE         SERVICE
22/tcp  open          ssh
25/tcp  open          smtp
80/tcp  open          http
139/tcp open          netbios-ssn
445/tcp open          microsoft-ds
68/udp  open|filtered dhcpc
```

**Samba version**

```
#smbd --version
Version 3.6.9-168.el6_5
```

workgroup is set up correctly in the smb.conf, nmb is running.

Comment: When you say its not in your network, do you mean you are trying to access this using your WAN connection?

Comment: @MatthewIfe I'm renting a vServer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most ISPs filter the netbios ports. If you nmap from your windows client you'll probably see the port is listed as `filtered` because your ISP is blocking it.

Try configuring a tunneling protocol such as `openvpn` and try using this setup instead.

Comment: Is there any reason why they do that? I just ran nmap on my client and as far as I can see, only httpd and ssh are open, 998 (actually the rest) is filtered. Do I have to configure openvpn on the samba server and do I need to connect with some sort of a openvpn client every time?

Comment: Well, check the firewall on your Windows machine too. And yes, you'd need to create a vpn server on your server and a vpn client on you're client.

Comment: Alright, thanks for helping me out. Seems like I'll set up OpenVPN since the windows firewall (and ISP firewall) is still blocking the netbios ports.